# Why can't Django REST Framework's HyperlinkedModelSerializer form URL?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

New to DRF and everything works as long as I don't include 'url' in fields. Here's what I've got:

Serializer:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('pk', 'short_desc', 'scheduled_date')
```

View Set:

```
class TaskViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = Task.objects.all().order_by('scheduled_date')
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
```

URLs:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'tasks', views.TaskViewSet)

urlpatterns = [

    [... bunch of non-REST URLs]

    # REST API
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
```

At runtime, printing router.urls gives me:

```
<RegexURLPattern api-root ^$>
<RegexURLPattern api-root ^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$>
<RegexURLPattern task-list ^tasks/$>
<RegexURLPattern task-list ^tasks\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$>
<RegexURLPattern task-detail ^tasks/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)/$>
<RegexURLPattern task-detail ^tasks/(?P<pk>[^/.]+)\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$>
```

Both  `[...]/tasks/` and `[...]/tasks/123/` work if I type them into my browser, which leads me to believe that task-list and task-detail views do, in fact exist.

Now I introduce a problem by adding 'url' to the serializer:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('url', 'pk', 'short_desc', 'scheduled_date')
```

After adding 'url' to fields, I get the following error:

> Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name
>   "task-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in
>   your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on
>   this field.

The DRF docs say:

> There needs to be a way of determining which views should be used for
>   hyperlinking to model instances. By default hyperlinks are expected to 
>   correspond to a view name that matches the style '{model_name}-detail',
>   and looks up the instance by a pk keyword argument.

Since I've verified that task-detail exists and that the corresponding URL `[...]/tasks/123/` works, I can't for the life of me figure out why DRF can't form the URL. Any ideas?

Comment: can you paste your models.py as well?

Comment: Did you set `URL_FIELD_NAME` explicitly in your settings?

Comment: `from rest_framework import settings`, `print(settings.URL_FIELD_NAME)` gives me an `'module' object has no attribute 'URL_FIELD_NAME'` error. It's supposed to default to 'url', no?

Comment: @Kunkka, short_desc is CharField, scheduled_date is DateField.

Comment: Yes, but i thought maybe it was set to something else and you should have put `URL_FIELD_NAME` in your fields instead of `'url'`. Anyway this a more error-prone way to do it.

Comment: Ok. When the docs say that it defaults to 'url' does that mean I should see the attribute with value 'url' or does it mean that DRF will use 'url' if the attribute isn't present?

Comment: If you are setting `fields` explicitly in `Meta`, than you should put whatever is in `URL_FIELD_NAME`, otherwise its `'url'` by default.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92659/discussion-between-ivan-and-bezewy).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inspired by clues revealed by Kunkka's answer, I have a solution that looks like this:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name="task:task-detail")

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('url', 'pk', 'short_desc', 'scheduled_date')
```

I.e. I've added an `url = [...]` line to the serializer I originally posted in my question. This solves the lookup problem which was presumably caused by DRF not knowing that 'task-detail' is actually in the 'task' namespace.

Any better solutions?

Comment: I was also able to solve the problem by modifying my urls.py files instead of modifying the serializers (as above). As long as the url files for DRF are not namespaced when included, there wasn't a problem.

Comment: Your comment is the only right answer for this problem.

Comment: Thanks. This works!. I believe that Django latest versions has problems with namespaces.

Answer (score 3):

Can you try this?

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('pk','url', 'short_desc', 'scheduled_date')

    def get_url(self,obj):
        request = self.context['request']
        return = {'self':reverse('task-detail',kwargs={'pk':obj.pk},request=request)}
```

Comment: In my version of Django (1.8.4), `django.core.urlresolvers.reverse` doesn't have a `request` argument. I changed the last line to `return reverse('task-detail', kwargs={'pk':obj.pk})` and it said that 0 patterns were tried. Changed `task-detail` to `task:task-detail` ("task" being the namespace for this app's views) and it came back without an error. However, the URLs produced didn't include the protocol or host-name. That said, this seems like a step forward and makes me think that maybe the  namespace is at the root of my problem.

Comment: something like return reverse('task-detail',kwargs={'pk':obj.pk})?