# Why is not `url` showing up in the DRF Response

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I can't get `url` to be returned when I use it in a `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`.

```py
# models.py
class Promotion(TimeStampedMixin, models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    # ...


# views.py
class PromotionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PromotionSerializer
    queryset = Promotion.objects.all()

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, context={'request': request})
        return Response(serializer.data)

# serializers.py
class PromotionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name="campaigns:promotion-detail", read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Promotion
        fields = (
            "url",
            "id",
            "name",
        )
```

The JSON output I receive when querying `curl -X GET http://localhost/api/promotion/2/`:

```js
{"id":2,"name":"My promotion"}
```

If I use `reverse` to check if the `view_name` in the `HyperlinkedRelatedField` exists, it prints the correct URL.

My question is: why doesn't the `url` show up in the response? It works any all my other views (comparing code with classes that works hasn't helped). Read the DRF documentation but I see nothing new (using version 3.11.0)

Comment: Does this lead you to an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33201520/why-cant-django-rest-frameworks-hyperlinkedmodelserializer-form-url

Comment: The solution mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/33207403/494739 worked, but I'd like to use the built-in functionality of DRF. I will use it temporarily until a proper solution has been found. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have a foreign key in your `Promotion` model?

Comment: @drec4s yes, the model has two FK-fields to models in other apps

Comment: But what is the url representation that you want? To any of those objects or to the current object?

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear; I want the URL representation to be to the *current* object. I can get URLs to the other FK-objects just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the url representation to the current object you should use the [HyperlinkedIdentityField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#hyperlinkedidentityfield)

```
class PromotionSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name="campaigns:promotion-detail", read_only=True
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Promotion
        fields = (
            "url",
            "id",
            "name",
        )
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I hadn't learned the difference between `HyperlinkedRelatedField` and `HyperlinkedIdentityField`

Comment: It's fairly simple. As the name suggests, you use the `HyperlinkedRelatedField` to get the URL of a _related_ object (foreign-key), and use the `HyperlinkedIdentityField` to get the URL of the _current_ object you are serializing.